# Batch file to delete absolute paths and leave only filename in multiple files

Tags: batch-file, variables, text, playlist, edt

I'm in over my head here.  I'm trying to write a .bat file that will go through every line in multiple .m3u playlist files to delete the path and leave only the filename.

Example input:

```
    C:\Users\username\Music\Dr. Dre\Dr. Dre & Snoop Doggy Dog - Ain't Nothin But A G-Thang.mp3
    C:\Users\username\Music\Ed Sheeran\x (Deluxe Edition)\04 Don't.mp3
    C:\Users\username\Music\Eric Church\Chief (2011)\06-eric_church-homeboy.mp3
```

Desired output:

```
    Dr. Dre & Snoop Doggy Dog - Ain't Nothin But A G-Thang.mp3
    x (Deluxe Edition)\04 Don't.mp3
    06-eric_church-homeboy.mp3
```

I have searched high and low with no luck getting the desired output.  I also don't have enough experience to make this easy.  In my multiple failed attempts, this is what I have come up with so far:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=* delims= eol=~" %%G in ('dir /b "C:\Users\username\Documents\Playlists\*.m3u"') do (
    SET Remove=*
    SET Result=%Remove:*\=% )
    ECHO %Result%
```

The approach I'm trying to use is to take each line and delete everything prior to, and including, the `\` symbol.  So far, I've been able to get the script to reach its end without an error but it's not actually doing anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read the output of `for /?` and note the "Modifiers" section. There is a modifier for the filename and for the extension. Alternatively use a plain `for`: `for %%G in ("C:\Users\username\Documents\Playlists\*.m3u") do echo %%~nxG`

Comment: If you wanted to use relative paths for that M3U file, then I'd expect it to reside in `C:\Users\username\Music` and contain: _line 1._ `Dr. Dre\Dr. Dre & Snoop Doggy Dog - Ain't Nothin But A G-Thang.mp3`, _line 2._ `Ed Sheeran\x (Deluxe Edition)\04 Don't.mp3`, and _line 3._ `Eric Church\Chief (2011)\06-eric_church-homeboy.mp3`. So based upon your 'Desired output' and the location of your M3U file, I would only, at best, expect one of those to work. However, as your playlists are all in `C:\Users\username\Documents\Playlists`, removing those will mean that nothing in that file will be play!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.m3u"') do (
 REM "%%G" contains the name+extension of each M3U file in turn
 for /F "usebackq delims=" %%q in ("%sourcedir%\%%G") do (
  rem %%q contains the entire contents of the file "%%G" - each such line is itself a full-filename
  for /f "delims=" %%s in ("%%q") do echo %%~nxs
 )
)>"%destdir%\%%~nxG"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

In the first line, the `dir/b` output is assigned to the *metavariable* `%%G`. The `/a-d` switch turns OFF directorynames, should a directory name fitting `*.m3u` be encountered.

`"delims="` assigns the line of `dir` output to `%%G` - the whole line, and nothing but the line. These lines are the names of the files encountered on scanning the directory.

Note the structure `for ... do ( ....whatever.... )>"filename"`. This means gather any output from `( ....whatever.... )` into a new file. (`>>` in place of `>` would append to an existing file, or create a new file if there is no existing file...) named using the `n`ame and e`X`tension of `%%G`. If you wanted `.txt` output files instead of `.M3u` (matching the extension in `%%G`) then you'd simply use `%%~nG.txt`.

Now we process each of the files "`%%G`". Since the name *may* include spaces, so the `usebackq` option needs to be used. Again, `delims=` will assign the entire line read from the file to `%%q`.

So `%%q` is a filename. Process this using `for/f` as a literal (by `"quoting"` it) and we can then use `%%~nxs` to "display" the "name and extension" of `%%s`.

So - what went wrong with your version?

Well, `tokens=*` and `delims=` essentially do the same thing (but the former suppresses leading-delimiters like spaces). `eol=~` would have truncated any filename-output from `dir` before the `~`, which may not have actually occurred - it's just a lurking problem.

Within the loop, you are setting `remove`. Two small problems here. First, better to use the syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty; in which case `var` becomes *undefined*) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

Second, and more seriously, when you use `Remove` in the next line, the value of `Remove` as it stood when the `for` was encountered would be used since your code uses `%Remove...%`. To use the *current* value as you expect, you need to turn on `delayedexpansion` (as you have) and use `!Remove...!`. Even there, you'd have attempted to assign the processed-value to `result`.

Using `set "remove=%%G"` would have been a little better (not what you want, as `%%G` is the name of the `.m3u` file - not its content, but better) and then you'd try to set `result` to `the contents of "remove" with all leading characters up to and including the  first "\" replaced by *nothing*`

So, had the content of the variable being processed been for example `C:\Users\username\Music\Ed Sheeran\x (Deluxe Edition)\04 Don't.mp3` as you apparently anticipated, then the result would have been simply to remove the `C:\`.

And then - `echo`ing `%result%` would have `echo`ed *nothing* since `result` had no value when the `for` was encountered. `echo !result!` may have worked a little better (`!` because the value has been modified by the loop)`but then`echo`with an argument that is resolved to *nothing* reports`echo is off` (or on, as the case may be), not an empty line as might be expected.

Complicated, innit? Nevermind - batch is fun once you get the hang of it.